# Fibonacci in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, fibonacci

My program is supposed to ask for a users input and do that many loops of a fibonacci sequence, I think I have the math down right and have codded it, however I keep getting a small infinite loop of numbers for a short while that do not make sense. I am still learning to code in NASM and would like to get better, please give me all the criticism you deem appropriate, what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you~

```
%include "io.mac"
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    msg1    db  "Please enter an number",0
.CODE
      .STARTUP
      PutStr    msg1;
nwln
    GetInt  AX; get int

nwln
    mov BX,1
    mov CX,2
nwln
loop1:
    sub BX,1 ;fn1-1
    sub CX,2; fn2 -2
    add BX,CX
    mov DX,BX
    sub BX,CX
    PutInt  DX
    cmp AX,CX
    je  done
    add BX,1
    add CX,1
    jmp loop1;
done:
      .EXIT
```

Comment: If you will comment your code, generally one comment per line of actual opcode, you'll get much more interest and response.

Comment: Okay thank you I will resubmit

Comment: If you just follow your register values and trace your loop a couple of iterations by hand, using the values you initialize, it looks like it would print `0`, then `-1`, etc, and `BX` and `CX` continue to go more negative. It's difficult to understand the relationship between the operations in this loop, and the properties of a Fibonacci sequence.